# Testing errors for Lottery hardhat project

Tags: hardhat, chainlink

I'm working on the Lottery project in Hardhat. I just finished up the unit testing part. When I run "yarn hardhat test" I get the following errors.........

```
  Raffle Unit Tests
    constructor
      ✔ Initializes the raffle correctly
    enterRaffle
      ✔ reverts when you don't pay enough
      ✔ records players when they enter
      ✔ emits event on enter
      1) doesn't allow entrance when raffle is calculating
    checkUpkeep
      ✔ returns false if people haven't sent any ETH
      2) returns false if raffle isn't open
      ✔ returns false if enough time hasn't passed
      ✔ returns true if enough time has passed, has players, eth, and is open
    performUpkeep
      3) it can only run when check upkeep is true
      ✔ reverts when check upkeep is false
      4) update the raffle state, emits an event, and calls the vrf coordinator
    fulfillRandomWords
      ✔ can only be called after performUpkeep
      5) picks a winner, resets the lottery, and sends money


  9 passing (2s)
  5 failing

  1) Raffle Unit Tests
       enterRaffle
         doesn't allow entrance when raffle is calculating:
     Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with custom error 'InvalidConsumer()'
    at VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.onlyValidConsumer (@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/mocks/VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.sol:72)
    at VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.requestRandomWords (@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/mocks/VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.sol:147)
    at Raffle.performUpkeep (contracts/Raffle.sol:118)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:64:3)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:538:9)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)
    at HardhatNode._mineBlockWithPendingTxs (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:1840:23)
    at HardhatNode.mineBlock (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:517:16)
    at EthModule._sendTransactionAndReturnHash (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/modules/eth.ts:1532:18)
  

  2) Raffle Unit Tests
       checkUpkeep
         returns false if raffle isn't open:
     Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with custom error 'InvalidConsumer()'
    at VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.onlyValidConsumer (@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/mocks/VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.sol:72)
    at VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.requestRandomWords (@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/mocks/VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.sol:147)
    at Raffle.performUpkeep (contracts/Raffle.sol:118)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:64:3)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:538:9)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)
    at HardhatNode._mineBlockWithPendingTxs (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:1840:23)
    at HardhatNode.mineBlock (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:517:16)
    at EthModule._sendTransactionAndReturnHash (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/modules/eth.ts:1532:18)
  

  3) Raffle Unit Tests
       performUpkeep
         it can only run when check upkeep is true:
     Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with custom error 'InvalidConsumer()'
    at VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.onlyValidConsumer (@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/mocks/VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.sol:72)
    at VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.requestRandomWords (@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/mocks/VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.sol:147)
    at Raffle.performUpkeep (contracts/Raffle.sol:118)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:64:3)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:538:9)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)
    at HardhatNode._mineBlockWithPendingTxs (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:1840:23)
    at HardhatNode.mineBlock (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:517:16)
    at EthModule._sendTransactionAndReturnHash (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/modules/eth.ts:1532:18)
  

  4) Raffle Unit Tests
       performUpkeep
         update the raffle state, emits an event, and calls the vrf coordinator:
     Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with custom error 'InvalidConsumer()'
    at VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.onlyValidConsumer (@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/mocks/VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.sol:72)
    at VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.requestRandomWords (@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/mocks/VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.sol:147)
    at Raffle.performUpkeep (contracts/Raffle.sol:118)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:64:3)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:538:9)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)
    at HardhatNode._mineBlockWithPendingTxs (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:1840:23)
    at HardhatNode.mineBlock (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:517:16)
    at EthModule._sendTransactionAndReturnHash (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/modules/eth.ts:1532:18)
  

  5) Raffle Unit Tests
       fulfillRandomWords
         picks a winner, resets the lottery, and sends money:
     TypeError: raffle.getLatestTimeStamp is not a function
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/unit/Raffle.test.js:153:58)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:64:3)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:538:9)
      at processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)



error Command failed with exit code 5.
```

I've tried fixing the problem with some of the suggestions from github issues that where posted on the course repo. I even changed the version of @chainlink/contract to 4.1 as suggested.

Here's a link to my github repo with the lottery project ...
https://github.com/whatTHEh3ll/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery

Can you tell me what I'm missing?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your unit test getLatestTimeStamp should be getLastTimeStamp, and raffleSate should be raffleState.
Also:

```
const raffleState = await raffle.getRaffleState
```

should be

```
const raffleState = await raffle.getRaffleState()
```

and

```
const tx = await raffle.performUpkeep
```

should be

```
const tx = await raffle.performUpkeep()
```

and in the fulfillRandomWords test block, startingBalance is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for responding...

I'm still getting errors. I see in the fulfillRandomWords test block Raffle.test.js. Below...

```
const startingBalance = await accounts[2].getBalance()
```

I see in Raffle.staging.test.js....

```
const winnerStartingBalance = await accounts[0].getBalance()
```

[my repo](https://github.com/whatTHEh3ll/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery)

[Patricks repo](https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).